# How to use a component inside another one in Storybook, when using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, storybook, angular-storybook

I have this folder structure, in which I have both my button and card components:

[image]

I declared a components.module.ts, and placed all my components in there, so I can import it in my app.module.ts, like this:

[image]

[image]

The problem is that when I try to use the ButtonComponents inside the CardComponent, by its selector ( app-button ), the component is not rendered. Why this happens?

Edit: I have also added the contents of button.component.ts and card.component.html:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share the contents of your `button.component.ts` and `card.component.html` files?

Comment: Sure. I edited the question and added those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem wasn't related to Angular, but to Storybook. When you want to be able to display a component in storybook which has dependencies to others, you should specify the module in the decorators property like so.

[image]